# Testing the correctness of mathematically oriented methods

Tags: unit-testing, math, testing

I'm implementing the two-dimensional Lanczos interpolation algorithm and I'm just done. As the modern day gentleman I am, before I release this method to the public, I want to unit test it. However I have always found it very difficult to unit test mathematical methods compared to general methods.

As some people know, the lanczos interpolation's results depends on multiple things, both the values you are interpolating, and the target *x* value. This makes it hard to test "known corner-cases" etc, as you would with regular methods.

One thing that I have thought about is to take another implementation of the Lanczos interpolation and then take some random values and compute them, and see if the results are the same, but this makes me depending on another library's correctness.

Anybody got any tips or can refer me to any literature?

EDIT: here's the code:

```
private val Radius = 3 // Taken from GDAL

private def lanczos(v: Double) =
    if (v == 0) 1
    else if (math.abs(v) > 0 && math.abs(v) < Radius)
      (Radius * math.sin(math.Pi * v) *
        math.sin(math.Pi * v / Radius) / math.pow(math.Pi * v, 2))
    else 0

override def cubicInterpolation(
    p: Array[Array[Double]],
    x: Double,
    y: Double): Double = {
    val xs = x.toInt - Radius + 1
    val xe = x.toInt + Radius

    val ys = y.toInt - Radius + 1
    val ye = y.toInt + Radius

    var accum = 0.0

    for (i <- xs to xe; j <- ys to ye) {
       accum += p(i)(j) * lanczos(y - j) * lanczos(x - i)
    }

    accum
}
```

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: You're always dependent on the correctness of your test, regardless of whether that requires external libraries or not.

Comment: That is true. But if you think of testing a mathematical method with multiple input parameters where you can't find any clear *corner cases*, how do I decide test parameters? How do I test them efficiently?

Comment: Well, I guess the purpose of unit tests are (a) documentation, and (b) to help you ascertain that your code is correct, (c) to protect against regression during future maintenance.  What failure modes could your code have?

Comment: When you say *failure modes* I don't really follow you, but I'm using this interpolation to rescale or reproject raster images. The individual cells in each raster can take whatever values possible and the rescaling or reprojection can be however weird they can be.

Comment: As in, where do you *anticipate* there might be bugs?

Comment: The function is maybe 20 lines of pure math, I anticipate that it's not going to be correct, and even if I stare myself blind through looking at the math I used as inspiration, chances are small that I've done everything correctly. So there, inside the function, I guess there might be bugs.

Comment: Perhaps testing using a datasource? That way you can continue to add new edge cases for a single unit test to prove. Potentially using a third party to calculate the results expected but not explicitly used in the test.

Comment: Yeah, the datasource must then be generated by an existing lib though, sounds like a smart thing to do though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One thing that I have thought about is to take another implementation of the Lanczos interpolation and then take some random values and compute them, and see if the results are the same (...)

This is what you should do. In fact, this is what you are most likely doing already when other unit tests are concerned - you *compute* expected values and test against them. The difference is, for most unit tests computations requires your brain or (at most) some basic calculator.

> (...) but this makes me depending on another library's correctness

As in every other testing case. You depend on your ability to correctly determine method flow, ability to parse string and predict results, ability to query XML with XPath and many, many others. Those are the cut-off points - you assume that they are correct and stop digging deeper. Otherwise, we'd all end up in never-ending testing spiral.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, otherwise there will always be one point of reference that must be correct.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas.

(1) You could compute the result directly from the definition, as represented in a computer algebra system. E.g. write `S(X, y) = sum(sum(s[i, j] * L(x - i) * L(y - j), j, floor(y) - a + 1, floor(y) + a), i, floor(x) - a + 1, floor(x) + a)` (according to Wikipedia; maybe you are working with a different definition) and then use that to compute the expected results. The idea is that this approach has a shorter leap from human-read formulas to computer code and thereafter might be a more reliable translation. I would be inclined to use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) because I'm familiar with it, but you could equally well use [Sympy](http://sympy.org) or Maple, etc. If you go down this road and need some help with Maxima, I'd be glad to help.

(2) Are there cases for which there are results known a priori? E.g. are there functions which are invariant under this transform? or which perhaps change in a well-known way? E.g. what happens to constant functions, linear functions, polynomials, trig functions?

Comment: I have implemented a number of different interpolations over the last few days and for all but the Lanczos interpolation, all has either had a solid MATLAB implementation to compare with, or has been as easy as calculating per hand. I've been thinking of this, btw I'm using the wikipedia formula, and I just feel that I can do a mistake in the other code I write, even though *I* think it looks the same as the definition. I'll rather take a fully fledged implementation and generated a data source to compare with, as suggested in other answers. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if your implementation is correct or not, writing test (unit or not) against a known correct source sounds like a great idea. Per definition those test will not be unit test, but in that case I would not care about that.

That kind of leads to the question: why did you write your own solution to an already solved problem? If you have to implement it yourself I guess there are 'lots' of unit test to be written.

Why don't you post your code?

Comment: Hi, I've posted my code. The problem is that it's in Scala and I don't want to bring in a huge dependency just for this, I haven't, by the way, found any lanczos interpolation implementation in Scala.